# why Invoke doesn't work in another class

Tags: c#, multithreading, serial-port, invoke

I would monitor data received on a Serial port with my pc and a Arduino. 
On the arduino, the sketch send thorugt the USB the string "aabb" evry 300ms. 
With pc I want listen, and in real time print the string in a control (`Textbox`). To do that, I create a new thread which listen in a Loop what arrives in Serial port, and when it happens it write by a Invoke the string in textbox. The procedures works if I deploy in the form's class but if I use a external class it doesn't. To explain better the matter, I paste the code of the class

```
class SerialPortManager
{
    public SerialPort Serial = new SerialPort();
    private Thread thr;
    private string Log;
    public TextBox textLog;
    public string LastString;
    public bool thrIsAlive;
    [Browsable(false)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    [IODescriptionAttribute("ControlInvokeRequiredDescr")]
    public bool InvokeRequired { get; private set; }

    //DISPOSE
    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.Dispose();
    }

    //SET Textobox LOG
    public void SetLogTxtB (TextBox txt)
    {
        textLog = txt;
    }

    //PORTE DISPONIBILI 
    public string[] Available_Ports()
    {
        return SerialPort.GetPortNames();
    }

    //COSTRUTTORI
    public SerialPortManager(string portname, int baudrate,bool InitializeConn)
    {
        Serial.BaudRate = baudrate;
        Serial.PortName = portname;
        if (InitializeConn == true) Serial.Open();
    }
    public SerialPortManager()
    {

    }

    //SETTA I PARAMETRI E INIZIALIZZA LA CONNESSIONE
    public void SetConnectionParam(string portname, int baudrate, bool initializeConn)
    {
        Serial.Close();
        Serial.Dispose();
        Serial = new SerialPort();
        Serial.BaudRate = baudrate;
        Serial.PortName = portname;
        if (initializeConn == true) Serial.Open();
    }

    //ASYNC LISTENER
    public void AsyncListener()
    {
        thrIsAlive = true;
        thr = new Thread(ThreadReader);
        thr.Start();
    }
    //PROCEDURA PER APPEND
    public void AppendTextBox(string value)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new Action<string>(AppendTextBox), new object[] { value });
            return;

        }
        textLog.Text += value;
    }

    private void Invoke(Action<string> action, params object[] v)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    void ThreadReader()
    {
        while (thrIsAlive)
        {
            string temp = Serial.ReadLine();
            LastString = temp;
            Log += LastString + "\n";
            AppendTextBox(LastString + "\n");
        }

    }
}
```

In the form I write three rows

```
SerialPortManager PortMan = new Driver_Arduin.SerialPortManager("COM3", 9600,true);
        PortMan.SetLogTxtB(textBox1);
        PortMan.AsyncListener();
```

If I try to run program it returns the error " cross-thread operation not allowed". Now, while I posting this ask, I decide to do a last try and change the method AppendTextBox to :

```
public void AppendTextBox(string value)
    {
        if (textLog.InvokeRequired)
        {
            try
            {
                textLog.Invoke(new Action<string>(AppendTextBox), new object[] { value });
                return;
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException)
            {
                thrIsAlive = false;
            }
        }
        textLog.Text += value;
    }
```

And It Finally works. Now ascertained the power of Stackoverflow that solved the problem before posting, I would know why my code works. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SerialPortManager you must use delegate instead windows control.

```
    class SerialPortManager
    {
        public SerialPort Serial = new SerialPort();
        private Thread thr;
        private string Log;
        //public TextBox textLog;
        public Action<string> textLog;
.....
```

Crete in you form simply method:

```
public void SetTextBoxText(string value)
    {
        if (textBox1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            try
            {
                textBox1.Invoke(new Action<string>(AppendTextBox), new object[] { value });
                return;
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException)
            {
                thrIsAlive = false;
            }
        }
        textBox1.Text += value;
    }
```

Set delegate to PortMan:

```
SerialPortManager PortMan = new Driver_Arduin.SerialPortManager("COM3", 9600,true);
        PortMan.SetLogTxtB=new Action<string>(SetTextBoxText);
        PortMan.AsyncListener();
```

If need output log to TextBox of PortMan call textLog delegate.

```
void ThreadReader()
    {
        while (thrIsAlive)
        {
            string temp = Serial.ReadLine();
            LastString = temp;
            Log += LastString + "\n";
            //AppendTextBox(LastString + "\n");
            textLog(LastString + "\n");
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from that your `Invoke` method in `SerialPortManager` should throw `NotImplementedException` the problem is that you define your own `InvokeRequired`/`Invoke`.

You need to use these methods provided by a WinForms control such that it knows whether your code is running inside the thread (UI thread) that created the control and how it can change context to this thread.

Actually it seems you may use your `SerialPortManager` but make use of `InvokeRequired`/`Invoke` of `textLog` like you're already doing in `AppendTextBox`.

BTW, `if (initializeConn == true)` is rather useless - `if (initializeConn)` is sufficient.